# why am i getting an error while using nested redis statements

Tags: node.js, redis

I am new to redis and i have been working through some examples and whenever iam using a nested redis statements in node js iam getting some error.
I have the following code:

```
var redis= require("redis");                                           
client = redis.createClient();              
client.on('connect',function(err){
if(err) console.log("not able to connect");
console.log("connected");});                      
client.RPUSH("pony","new"); 
client.RPUSH("pony","val");                                
client.LINDEX("pony",-1,function(err,reply){
if(err) console.log("oops");
console.log(reply);
client.LREM("pony",-1,reply,function(err,rep){
    if(err) console.log("error");
    else console.log(rep);
});})                                                          
client.quit();
```

I am getting the output

> connected,
>   val,
>   error

Here the reply from LINDEX is a string "val" which iam passing it to LREM.

Why is the nested client.lrem not taking the value of reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. But `client.quit()` gets executed before your `client.LREM("pony",-1,reply,function(err,rep){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(rep);
});`

could execute and you are getting error

`{ [AbortError: Stream connection ended and command aborted. It might have been processed.]
  code: 'NR_CLOSED',
  command: 'LREM',
  args: [ 'pony', -1, 'val' ] }`

`client.quit()` executes right after

```
client.LINDEX("pony",-1,function(err,reply){
if(err) console.log("oops");
console.log("##" + reply);
```

`client.LREM()` requires more time to execute and because of that it executes after javascript event queue gets empty ( That's how javascript works).

So I suggest you can use **promise** (like "q") or **async.series()** to execute code serially and make sure if all operations are execute completely then close redis client connection.

Or another simple option is do not close redis client connection.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out :) I called client.quit();inside the client.lindex statement and it worked fine